# How to make node modules global with ember?

Tags: node.js, ember.js, bower, ember-cli

I created a new ember project with `ember new my-application`. By default, it will download and extract all modules in the "node_modules" directory. I don't want it because it will be include in my git repo, when I do a global search, it includes all modules, etc.

Is there a way to install all modules globally? Is it a best practice?

Comment: `ember new` also adds a .gitignore which has both `node_modules` and `bower_components` in it so it shouldn't end up in git. It will be search though which can be a bit annoying but most editors have some way to ignore this.

Comment: You're right. My .gitignore was missing. Add an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Yeah I was in a bit of a hurry so a comment felt better for the short idea I had. Wrote an answer with a bit more information covering all your points now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute `ember new` it will add a .gitignore to your project that excludes `node_modules`, `bower_components`, `tmp` and `dist` so those should never end up in your repository.

The searching part has no general solution though most editors you use can somehow exclude folders from being searched so I would look into it that way.

Node modules can be installed globally but you will quite quickly run into problems when you need different versions for different projects. Ember CLI is installed globally initially (`npm install -g ember-cli`) which enables you to do `ember new` from anywhere but then there is also a local one inside each project so that you can upgrade your globally installed one without messing with all your older projects.